# I want to use SimpleXML to export/import a SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, simple-framework

So my app uses a content provider and SQLite database, similar to the Google notepad example.  I found SimpleXML and wanted to use that to import/export the database so it could be transfered between devices.  The only example I have found is this [example.](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/)
I would like to not have to write some intermediary classes to transfer the database in/out.  Has anyone found an easy way, maybe even doing it without simplexml?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to import/export the complete database or only parts of it. For the case the complete database should be transfered you might just copy the database file itself which is normally stored in /data/data/YOUR_APP/databases

Comment: Whole database.  I'm trying to make it easy(ier) for the user to do.

Comment: what i read before about sqlite backup/restore: SQLite databases are completely self-contained files and are portable — you can just copy the entire file straight to the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DataXmlExporter extends DataBaseDemoActivity {

   static final String DATASUBDIRECTORY = "bookwormdata";

  // private final SQLiteDatabase db;
   private XmlBuilder xmlBuilder;
   Button butt;

  /* public DataXmlExporter(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
      this.db = db;

   }*/

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main7);


  butt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.exportxml);
  String exportFileNamePrefix=exportxml;
    // public void export(final String dbName, final String exportFileNamePrefix) throws IOException {
      Log.i(Constants._COUNT, "exporting database - " + dbname + " exportFileNamePrefix=" + exportFileNamePrefix);

      try {
        xmlBuilder = new XmlBuilder();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      xmlBuilder.start(dbname);

      // get the tables
      String sql = "select * from dept";
      Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[0]);

      if (c.moveToFirst()) {

          //while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String tableName ="dept";//c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dep_id"));

            // skip metadata, sequence, and uidx (unique indexes)
            if (!tableName.equals("android_metadata") && !tableName.equals("sqlite_sequence")
                     && !tableName.startsWith("uidx")) {
               try {
                exportTable(tableName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
         // }
        }
      String xmlString = null;
    try {
        xmlString = xmlBuilder.end();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      try {
        writeToFile(xmlString, exportFileNamePrefix + ".xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      Log.i(Constants._COUNT, "exporting database complete");
      Toast.makeText(DataXmlExporter.this, "DB xml backup Successfully", 2000).show();

      butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(DataXmlExporter.this, DataBaseDemoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                        }
        });
   }

   private void exportTable(final String tableName) throws IOException {
      xmlBuilder.openTable(tableName);
      String sql = "select * from " + tableName;
      Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[0]);
      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         int cols = c.getColumnCount();
         do {
            xmlBuilder.openRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                /*if(i==6)
                {
                    //String id = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("photo"));
                    String str = new String(image);
                    xmlBuilder.addColumn(c.getColumnName(i), str);
                }*/
               xmlBuilder.addColumn(c.getColumnName(i), c.getString(i));
            }
            xmlBuilder.closeRow();
         } while (c.moveToNext());
      }
      c.close();
      xmlBuilder.closeTable();
   }

   private void writeToFile(final String xmlString, final String exportFileName) throws IOException {
      File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DataXmlExporter.DATASUBDIRECTORY);
      if (!dir.exists()) {
         dir.mkdirs();
      }
      File file = new File(dir, exportFileName);
      file.createNewFile();

      ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(xmlString.getBytes());
      FileChannel channel = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
      try {
         channel.write(buff);
      } finally {
         if (channel != null) {
            channel.close();
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * XmlBuilder is used to write XML tags (open and close, and a few attributes)
    * to a StringBuilder. Here we have nothing to do with IO or SQL, just a fancy StringBuilder. 
    * 
    * @author ccollins
    *
    */
   static class XmlBuilder {
      private static final String OPEN_XML_STANZA = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
      private static final String CLOSE_WITH_TICK = "'>";
      private static final String DB_OPEN = "<database name='";
      private static final String DB_CLOSE = "</database>";
      private static final String TABLE_OPEN = "<table name='";
      private static final String TABLE_CLOSE = "</table>";
      private static final String ROW_OPEN = "<row>";
      private static final String ROW_CLOSE = "</row>";
      private static final String COL_OPEN = "<col name='";
      private static final String COL_CLOSE = "</col>";

      private final StringBuilder sb;

      public XmlBuilder() throws IOException {
         sb = new StringBuilder();
      }

      void start(final String dbName) {
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.OPEN_XML_STANZA);
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.DB_OPEN + dbName + XmlBuilder.CLOSE_WITH_TICK);
      }

      String end() throws IOException {
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.DB_CLOSE);
         return sb.toString();
      }

      void openTable(final String tableName) {
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.TABLE_OPEN + tableName + XmlBuilder.CLOSE_WITH_TICK);
      }

      void closeTable() {
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.TABLE_CLOSE);
      }

      void openRow() {
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.ROW_OPEN);
      }

      void closeRow() {
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.ROW_CLOSE);
      }

      void addColumn(final String name, final String val) throws IOException {
         sb.append(XmlBuilder.COL_OPEN + name + XmlBuilder.CLOSE_WITH_TICK + val + XmlBuilder.COL_CLOSE);
      }
   }

}
```

Try this. It's work for me.

Comment: Sure. This program used to export a particular table from a database  in form of XML file. You could transfer this XML file to your SD card. If you run this code on device check this path /data/data/YOUR_APP/databases or in emulator click DDMS/file Explorer option in Eclipse.

Comment: you worked hard for this code, as I see you are building xml file row by row, however as I think the result may not be a "Well Formed" xml file, because xml has syntax and you do not check it, for example if data contains greater then symbol ">" you have to replace it with &gt; to get valid xml file. so I am looking for a way to build it automatically to guarantee correct syntax and avoid errors could be made by data itself.